# Load More / Show Less issues using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Question(s):** Provided below, I am encountering a few issues, they are:

<strike>**1.)** where `$('.resume_container_item:lt(' + x + ')').show();` is located, it is only showing the first 4 items in the first container - it should show the first 4 items in all containers.</strike>

**2.)** the `if` statement here

```
if (x == size_item) { // ISSUE LIES HERE - For some reason, it does not want to fade out once reached...
    $('.resume_view_more').fadeOut(250);
}
```

=========================================================================

As for the css, I have the `.resume_container_item` and the `.resume_show_less` classes as `display: none;`

Here is the full code:

```
size_item = $('.resume_container_item').size();
x = 4;
$('.resume_container').each(function( index ) {
  $(this).children('.resume_container_item:lt(' + x + ')').show(); 
}); // Fixed with help from n01ze
$('.resume_view_more').click(function() {
  var $parent = $(this).parent();
  x = (x + 4 <= size_item) ? x + 4 : size_item;
  $parent.find('.resume_container_item:lt(' + x + ')').slideDown();
  $parent.find('.resume_show_less').fadeIn(500);
  if (x == size_item) { // ISSUE LIES HERE - For some reason, it does not want to fade out once reached...
    $('.resume_view_more').fadeOut(250);
  }
  return false;
});
$('.resume_show_less').click(function() {
  var $parent = $(this).parent();
  x = (x - 4 < 4) ? 4 : x - 4;
  $parent.find('.resume_container_item').not(':lt(' + x + ')').slideUp();
  $parent.find('.resume_view_more').fadeIn(500);
  if (x == 4) {
    $('.resume_show_less').fadeOut(250);
  }
  return false;
});
```

Any suggestions and/or thoughts on how to correct this is greatly appreciated...I've been at this for hours and can't seem to figure out why this is occurring...

**UPDATE:**

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvwc0ohj/3/)

**UPDATE 2:**

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvwc0ohj/11/)

With this update, issue #1 has been corrected with the help of **n01ze**

Comment: Can you please share the html markup as well. Kindly make a codepen and share the link.

Comment: Sure, give me a second :)

Comment: here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvwc0ohj/3/)

Comment: I can't see your error, the "Load more" is hiding when all 16 items are shown, and this is actually what your code is meant to do..

Comment: @Yuri, For the most part - it's done.  If you check out the second update fiddle, and start playing around with the "load more" and "show less" buttons/links for the two containers you will clearly see issues still.  For example, click the "load more" button in the "misc. stuff" section twice - then click the "load more" button in the "programming lang." section once - that section opens up 8 items when it should have opened up 4 - then click the "show less" button once on that side - and then once on the "misc. stuff" side...You see that the "misc. stuff" side closes all but 4 - when it...

Comment: should have closed only 4 at a time.  Other weird things occur as well - just play around with it for a minute or two switching back and forth between the two sides...The fadeIn and Out parts have been achieved to some extent - now the issue lies where it should only open/close 4 items at a time no matter what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the second fiddle occurs because you rely on a single variable `x` to handle two different counters.

You can check how many items you are showing by counting `:visible` elements within the container

```
$('.resume_view_more').click(function() {
  var $parent = $(this).parent();
  var size_item = $parent.children('.resume_container_item').size();
  var tmp_x = $parent.children('.resume_container_item:visible').size();
  tmp_x = (tmp_x + 4 <= size_item) ? tmp_x + 4 : size_item;
  $parent.find('.resume_container_item:lt(' + tmp_x + ')').slideDown();
  $parent.find('.resume_show_less').fadeIn(500);
  if (tmp_x == size_item) { 
    $parent.children('.resume_view_more').fadeOut(250);
  }
  return false;
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvwc0ohj/14/) here

Comment: Thank you very much!  I had a feeling it had to do with the way I was counting the items but didn't think about creating a second "counter".  Again, much appreciated - I spent so many hours on trying to get this to work...lol.  Ty.

Answer (score 1):

Try this , to load 4 items in each container,

```
//$('.resume_container_item:lt(' + x + ')').show();  //Comment this line

$('.resume_container').each(function( index ) {
  $( this ).children('.resume_container_item:lt(' + x + ')').show(); 
});
```

**Edit 2 : for point 2**

use inside your loop

```
$('.resume_view_more').click(function() {
  var $parent = $(this).parent();
  size_item = $parent.children('.resume_container_item').size(); //This will fix it

..... rest codes

$parent.children('.resume_view_more').fadeOut(250); //Try this to hide specific link
```

**FINAL CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
/*!
 *  Author: Michael R. Draemel
 *          http://draemel.com/
 */

size_item = $('.resume_container_item').size();
x = 4;
//$('.resume_container_item:lt(' + x + ')').show(); // ISSUE LIES HERE - Need to figure out how to show first 4 items in each container
$('.resume_container').each(function( index ) {
  $( this ).children('.resume_container_item:lt(' + x + ')').show();
  var chld_size = $(this).children('.resume_container_item').size();

  if(chld_size <= x) {
   $(this).children('.resume_view_more').hide();
   $(this).children('.resume_show_less').hide();
  }
});
$('.resume_view_more').click(function() {
  var $parent = $(this).parent();
  size_item = $parent.children('.resume_container_item').size(); //This will fix it
  x = (x + 4 <= size_item) ? x + 4 : size_item;
  $parent.find('.resume_container_item:lt(' + x + ')').slideDown();
  $parent.find('.resume_show_less').fadeIn(500);
  if (x == size_item) { // ISSUE LIES HERE - For some reason, it does not want to fade out once reached...
    $parent.children('.resume_view_more').fadeOut(250);
  }
  return false;
});
$('.resume_show_less').click(function() {
  var $parent = $(this).parent();
  size_item = $parent.children('.resume_container_item').size(); //This will fix it
  x = (x - 4 < 4) ? 4 : x - 4;
  $parent.find('.resume_container_item').not(':lt(' + x + ')').slideUp();
  $parent.find('.resume_view_more').fadeIn(500);
  if (x == 4) {
   // $('.resume_show_less').fadeOut(250);
   $parent.children('.resume_show_less').fadeOut(250);
  }
  return false;
});

});
```

Comment: Perfect!  One down, any ideas about the second one?  I don't want to mark this answer as correct just yet since I had a two part question.

Comment: @Michael ohh sorry , there is one mre .. let me provide you the solution. thanks

Comment: that is very close - however, now it is clearing all the `.resume_view_more` links in every container - would I need to apply a similar `.each` statement like you did for question 1?

Comment: I did - and tested it out - still no cigar...additional issues arise if adding that in such as if a user clicks on the `load more` link a few times, but doesn't click it one last time before it should disappear, and then clicks on the other containers `load more` link, weird stuff starts to happen...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue lies here: `if (x == size_item)` - As you can see on the second if statement for the `.resume_show_less` click function, I have it specified to exactly 4 `==` or equal to...I need to somehow fix it for the first `if` statement.  I've tried `if(x <= size_item)` and a few other ways, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Maybe adding a counter of each `.resume_container_item`?  And then stating that once the last `item` in the `container` has been reached, `fadeOut` the `load more` link?

Comment: You need to do the same for show less also , and need to modify your code also

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I have tested it - take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvwc0ohj/7/) - play around with the `load more` and `show less` links for both containers - weird things start occuring...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106188/discussion-between-n01ze-and-michael).